# How to add a folder full of ui files/scripts via nuget package?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, nuget, nuget-package

I want to bundle a [ui] folder which has a bunnch of javascript, css and html files in the NuGet package I am creating.

The intent is that when the user installs my nuget package this folder in its entirety should be added to his project.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the folder into an existing NuGet package, you could use [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) to add them with below steps.

1. Open the NuGet Package with NuGet Package Explorer.
2. Click CONTENT menu to choose Add -> Content Folder.
3. Drag your UI folder into the content folder that you added.

If the NuGet package project doesn’t have pack as a package, you could add the UI Folder into your project and the **Build Action** of the files in this folder **set as Content**. Then please pack this project with following command with [nuget.exe](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html).

> Nuget.exe pack ProjectName.csproj